# Can an onset of a syllable be CV?

Tags: phonology, syllables

Hypothetically speaking, can a CVVC sequence be segmented into a CV onset, a V nucleus and a C coda?

Or is it the case that the VV will always be the nucleus?

Comment: this seems like it would depend on whether you consider segments like i̯ to be included in C or V. Whilst I'd typically expect them to be included in C but not V, it wouldn't surprise if some authors did the reverse (i.e. include them in V but not C)

Answer (score 2):

From a phonotactic perspective, the symbol V is often used to mean "acts as a syllable nucleus". And by this definition, the question doesn't really make sense. If V is defined as being part of the nucleus, it will by definition be used as part of the nucleus.

So it'll depend what definitions you're using. Maybe you're defining V to mean a particular set of phonemes in your language, which *aren't* always in the nucleus. In Hittite, for example, some scholars say that `[j]` and `[w]` are just allophones of `/i/` and `/u/` when they're not in the nucleus. So if you include those in your definition of V, then Hittite can have VVC syllables. (Not CVVC in this case because `/i/` and `/u/` insist on remaining nuclei in that context, so you'd have CV.VC, as in *lag**nuan**zi* "they fell".)

But, "it can happen if you define things so that it can happen" isn't a very satisfying answer. If you nail down your particular definition of the symbols of V and C that you're using, we might be able to answer in a more useful way.

Comment: … unless you count /kw/ as being /ku/ as well? You wouldn’t say that _kuenzi_ is /ku.en.tsi/, would you?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm looking specifically at Kloekhorst's (somewhat controversial) analysis here; he says that one is a single phoneme /kʷ/ rather than /kw/.

Answer (score 1):

That is how some people deal with the concept "short diphthong", so that [dŭat] could have a CV onset and one nuclear vowel, and [duat] would have two nuclear vowels. Justifying that analysis is a bit of a challenge in light of the existence of alternative analyses, but yes it is certainly a theoretical possibility. The main obstacle is showing that [dwat] is not the correct analysis. The second runner-up alternative analysis is that "mora" is an independent representational object whereby a vowel can one mora or two, a consonant can have one mora or two, and a diphthong can have one mora or two. There is plenty of evidence to support the construct "mora" and the related possible contrasts, so the question then becomes "Why posit a CV onset?". We'd have to see some data.